# Stored Procedure giving different result on same database with same argument

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, edmx

I have a stored procedure which gives different result in only a specific case.

When I call it from SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2, it gives me 0 as output.

When I call it from C# class file. It gives me 1 as output.

I am using edmx file, and it is updated for sure.

The call is something like below from SSMS [SQL Server Management Studio]

```
exec proc_GetPrimaryKeyUsageCount 62, 'tblFormula'
```

This gives output as 0

The same stored procedure is called from C# file is like below

```
_db.GetPrimaryKeyUsageCount(62, "tblFormula");
```

This gives output as 1

The stored procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_GetPrimaryKeyUsageCount (  
 @PrimaryKeyColumnId INT  
 ,@PrimaryKeyTable NVARCHAR(max)  
 --,@Response INT OUTPUT  
 )  
AS  
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @counter INT  
 DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(max)  
 DECLARE @ForeignKey TABLE (  
  child_table VARCHAR(max)  
  ,child_fk_column VARCHAR(max)  
  )  
 DECLARE @child_table VARCHAR(max)  
 DECLARE @child_fk_column VARCHAR(max)  

 SET @counter = 0  

 INSERT INTO @ForeignKey  
 SELECT child_table = c.TABLE_NAME  
  ,child_fk_column = c.COLUMN_NAME  
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE p  
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS pc ON pc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = p.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA  
  AND pc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = p.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE c ON c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = pc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA  
  AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pc.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
 WHERE EXISTS (  
   SELECT 1  
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
   WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'IsDeleted'  
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = p.TABLE_SCHEMA  
    AND TABLE_NAME = p.TABLE_NAME  
    AND p.TABLE_NAME = @PrimaryKeyTable  
   )  

 DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR  
 FOR  
 SELECT child_table  
  ,child_fk_column  
 FROM @ForeignKey  

 OPEN db_cursor  

 FETCH NEXT  
 FROM db_cursor  
 INTO @child_table  
  ,@child_fk_column  

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
 BEGIN  
  PRINT 'select count(*) from ' + CAST(@child_table AS VARCHAR) + ' where ' + CAST(@child_fk_column AS VARCHAR) + ' = ' + CAST(@PrimaryKeyColumnId AS VARCHAR)  

  SET @sqlCommand = 'select @cnt=count(*) from ' + CAST(@child_table AS VARCHAR) + ' where ' + CAST(@child_fk_column AS VARCHAR) + ' = ' + CAST(@PrimaryKeyColumnId AS VARCHAR)  

  EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand  
   ,N'@cnt int OUTPUT'  
   ,@cnt = @counter OUTPUT  

  IF @counter > 0  
   BREAK  

  FETCH NEXT  
  FROM db_cursor  
  INTO @child_table  
   ,@child_fk_column  
 END  

 SELECT @counter AS [PrimaryKeyUsageCount]  
END
```

---

1st argument is Id of the primary key and 2nd argument is the name of the table having that primary key.

The Procedure returns the count of the usage of primary key in other tables in same database. If it finds even 1 occurrence, it will return that count otherwise 0.

If anything extra is needed please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes, which could cause the problem.
The INSERT should be like that:

```
INSERT INTO @ForeignKey  
 SELECT c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME  
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE p  
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS pc ON pc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = p.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA  
  AND pc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = p.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE c ON c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = pc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA  
  AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pc.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
 WHERE EXISTS (  
   SELECT *  
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS isc 
   WHERE isc.COLUMN_NAME = 'IsDeleted'  
    AND isc.TABLE_SCHEMA = p.TABLE_SCHEMA  
    AND isc.TABLE_NAME = p.TABLE_NAME  
    AND p.TABLE_NAME = @PrimaryKeyTable  
   )
```

After cursor loop shoud be:

```
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: But that is not at all my issue. My issue is regarding the value that I am getting in my mapped function.